# Schemacrawler cannot output the schema from DB2 (and Oracle) server in JSON format

Tags: oracle, db2, schemacrawler

I am trying to use [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/) to extract schema information on db2 test database.

When running the `schema` command with text or html format, things work as expected:

```
./schemacrawler.sh --server=db2 --host=127.0.0.1 --port=50000 --database=sample --schemas=DB2INST1 --user="db2inst1" --password=password --info-level=standard --command=schema --tables='.*\.P.*' 


System Information
========================================================================

generated by                              SchemaCrawler 16.9.2          
generated on                              2020-07-17 01:50:58.987909    



Tables
========================================================================



DB2INST1.PRODUCT                                                 [table]
------------------------------------------------------------------------
  PID                               VARCHAR(10) NOT NULL        
  NAME                              VARCHAR(128)                
  PRICE                             DECIMAL(30, 2)              
  PROMOPRICE                        DECIMAL(30, 2)              
  PROMOSTART                        DATE                        
  PROMOEND                          DATE                        
  DESCRIPTION                       XML                         

Primary Key

PK_PRODUCT                                                 [primary key]
  PID                                                           

Indexes

PK_PRODUCT                                                [unique index]
  PID                               ascending                   

(... and so on ...)
```

Now I want to output it in JSON format for data integration purpose. So I tried running the `schema` command with output in json format, and it failed ([full log here](https://gist.github.com/stndn/ff6d28679c5c5dc0f96029ffc11fc1ba)):

```
SchemaCrawler 16.9.2

Error: Unknown command <schema>

Re-run SchemaCrawler with just the
-h
option for help

Or, re-run SchemaCrawler with an additional
--log-level=CONFIG
option for details on the error
```

I have also tried it with [the command `serialize`](https://www.schemacrawler.com/serialize.html), and it failed as well ([full log here](https://gist.github.com/stndn/30b8cdc13243ddcc64dabe80698b91d0)):

```
SchemaCrawler 16.9.2

Error: Unknown command <serialize>

Re-run SchemaCrawler with just the
-h
option for help

Or, re-run SchemaCrawler with an additional
--log-level=CONFIG
option for details on the error
```

As an aside, I am also facing similar issue when running against Oracle server.

So, two questions:

1. How can I extract the schema information from db2 server in JSON format?
2. How can I do the same for Oracle server?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sutandiono,

You can absolutely extract the schema metadata in JSON format for IBM DB2 and Oracle databases. Your log is not complete, so I cannot see the stacktrace right at the the end. What I can see, though, is that you have Jackson jar files on your classpath, which is good. Other than that, you can try with an additional command-line argument of `--output-format json`. (Please let me know if this works.) In the next SchemaCrawler version, you will get a better error message, like this "Error: Output format  not supported for command ", which will help you.

Sualeh Fatehi, [SchemaCrawler](https://www.schemacrawler.com/)

Comment: Hi, @Sualeh Fatehi, thank you for looking into this. I have uploaded new gist [over here](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/stndn/97f62c7477543df92c80063e4772129a/raw/2375c670e14f862936a5cab5be7a6c9c96b55d08/db2-schema-error-on-json-output.txt) for your reference. This one includes the argument `--output-format=json`, which I skipped previously because according to [the changelog](https://www.schemacrawler.com/changes-report.html), the JSON output was removed in 16.2.2. We also tried `serialize` with [different error](https://gist.github.com/stndn/4de0d23f25b74412e60c035d3de27437). Thank you.

Comment: Sutandiono, you will need to use the serialize command for JSON output. For some reason, the Gist is still cutting out the actual error. It could be that the issue that you are seeing is the same one reported here - https://github.com/schemacrawler/SchemaCrawler/issues/346 - I am looking into that issue, so please follow that thread on GitHub.

Comment: Hi, @Sualeh Fatehi, please look at this [raw gist](https://gist.githubusercontent.com/stndn/4de0d23f25b74412e60c035d3de27437/raw/0f3e16555b87295accd88361450c2a16a3549c3b/db2-serialize-error) that shows the complete error on `serialize`. Meanwhile, I will follow the same reported issue on github. Thank you again for looking into this issue.

Comment: Yes, that will be fixed in issue #346 referenced above

Comment: Hi, @Sualeh Fatehi, just replying here to inform you that the issue was fixed in SchemaCrawler 16.9.3. Thank you for the help, and thank you for providing such a great tool :)